# Laravel Model not binding in controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel model `PurhaseOrder` and a controller `PurchaseOrdersController` with a method `show`

If I typecast the method with an an interger:

```
public function show(int $purchaseOrder)
{
        dd(PurchaseOrder::find($purchaseOrder));
}
```

Then `dd()` dumps out what I expect ( the record in the database where the id matches $purchaseOrder)

However if instead I do this:

```
public function show(PurchaseOrder $purchaseOrder)
{
        dd($purchaseOrder);
}
```

Then `$purchaseOrder` is an empty model and not populated with any data from the database.  My route looks like this:

```
Route::get('purchase-orders/{purchase_orders}/show', ['as' => 'admin.purchase-orders.show', 'uses' => 'PurchaseOrdersController@show']);
```

This is code that I've inherited and I'm trying to update from Laravel 5.3 to Laravel 5.6.  Where should I be looking to solve this issue of the model not being populated correctly?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The implicit [model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding) requires you to match the variable name with the route parameter name, so for example, for the following method:

```
public function show(PurchaseOrder $purchaseOrder)
{
    dd($purchaseOrder);
}
```

The route should contain the matching parameter name, for example:

```
Route::get('purchase-orders/{purchaseOrder}/show', [
    'as' => 'admin.purchase-orders.show',
    'uses' => 'PurchaseOrdersController@show'
]);
```

Notice that, the method parameter name in `show` method which is `$purchaseOrder` and the route parameter name `{purchaseOrder}` both are same and that's a requirement for the implicit model binding, otherwise you have to do an explicit model binding, where you've to explicitly tell the framework about your parameter name, for example (in `RouteServiceProvider`):

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::model('purchase_orders', App\PurchaseOrder::class);
}
```

This will tell the framework that, if there is the `{purchase_orders}` parameter name available in the route then resolve/bind an instance of `PurchaseOrder` model into the given method for that route.

Comment: Most Welcome :-)

Comment: OMG this took me forever to figure this out, and thankfully finding this post. In my web.php I created a resource with a capital letter so it never could resolve the binding: Route::resource('Accounts', 'AccountsController'); I changed it to Route::resource('accounts', 'AccountsController'); So running artisian works nicely: ie make:controller AccountsController -r -m  Models/Account. Hope this helps someone else on something similar to this issue

Comment: I have been trying to figure out the same issue, had I not found this answer no idea how much longer I would have been searching for an answer. Thanks.